# using kubernetes secrets in SSLContext

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I am doing POC to check if we can connect to an API, for that I use the below code.

```
# Define the client certificate settings for https connection
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
print(type(context))
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=CERT, keyfile=KEY, password=PW)
 
# Create a connection to submit HTTP requests
connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, port=443, context=context)
 
# Use connection to submit a HTTP POST request
connection.request(method="GET", url=request_url, headers=request_headers)
 
# Print the HTTP response from the IOT service endpoint
response = connection.getresponse()
print(response.status, response.reason)
data = response.read()
print(data)
```

these two variables (CERT and KEY), i get the secrets via kubernetes files and convert them to strings. Is there alternate ways to load the downloaded secrets into context object instead of using load_cert_chain method (since this one needs files). I know this is not ideal, but since I am doing only POC I just want to see if this is doable.

Comment: This is one way. You may also make kubernetes set the env variables to read from. This will avoid creating/mounting he file.

Comment: Steal this code https://github.com/coderanger/streamdeck/blob/master/src/veranda/kubernetes.py#L38-L61